# PGROuting 2 : Getting nearest node to a given point (with lat - long given)

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, point, latitude-longitude

I have a point whose latitude and longitude (only) are known, and a table of nodes with their geom. I want to find the closest node in the table to the given point.

I think I can achieve this with pgr_findNearestNodeDwithin function, but i cannot find the exact syntax of the function and the parameters it takes.

Any pointers in this direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the nearest point you only need a little bit PostGIS. With PostGIS 2.0 or higher you can use [nearest neighbor KNN gist functionality](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/geometry_distance_centroid.html).

I assume you have a table with all nodes ("vertices"):

```
SELECT * FROM vertices 
    ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(lon lat)',4326) 
    LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score -2):

find_nearest_node_within_distance, in matching.sql

SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT find_nearest_node_within_distance(
                'POINT(x y)',
                0.5,
                'test_2po_4pgr') as x
        ) AS foo

Comment: is that function available for pgrouting version 2?

Comment: It is in matchinq.sql which is part of pgrouting or postgis ( i do not remember exactly ).

Comment: matching.sql is not included in pgRouting 2 anymore.