# pgrouting 2: missing pgr_findnearestnodedwithin function

Tags: pgrouting, postgis-2.0, update

With the PgRouting 1.5 I was using the find_nearest_node_within_distance function and it works, but now I'm moving the project to PgRouting 2 + Postgis 2 + PostgreSQL 9.1, and now that function, I think, was renamed to pgr_findnearestnodedwithin but when I try to execute the query I get the following error

```
ERROR:  function pgr_findnearestnodedwithin(unknown, numeric, unknown) does not exist
```

I was looking if there is a new way to import this function but I didn't have success. please help. there are something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [PGROuting 2 : Getting nearest node to a given point (with lat - long given)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67513/pgrouting-2-getting-nearest-node-to-a-given-point-with-lat-long-given)

Answer (score 1):

The function does not exist (anymore) in pgRouting 2.0
All available functions are listed in the documentation: http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/index.html

With PostGIS 2.0 there is a very easy and fast way to achieve this using KNN index, for example:

```
SELECT *
   FROM node_table 
   ORDER BY the_geom <-> "<your point geometry>"
   LIMIT 1;
```