# Get km route between two points with lat / lng

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I'm doing the following query to get the distance between two points with pgrouting:

```
SELECT
        sum(cost) AS cost
FROM pgr_dijkstra(
                'SELECT id, source, target, km as cost FROM at_2po_4pgr',
                50347, 32988, false, false
        );
```

It turns out that the source and destination comes from nominatim geocode coordinates in, and I do not know how to use the coordinates as parameter in sql.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `start` and `end` parameter are node ID's. If you have the vertices table, then you can use the following query to [find the nearest node](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/67537/800) to your point coordinates.

```
SELECT * FROM vertices 
    ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(lon lat)',4326) 
    LIMIT 1;
```

If you don't have the vertices table, then you can (re)create it with the [`pgr_createVerticesTable` function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/109026/800).

You could write your own custom wrapper function to put all this together. The [pgRouting workshop gives a simple example](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html#route-between-lat-lon-points-and-return-ordered-geometry-with-heading), that you can use to get started.

Comment: Very good !!! Thank !! Perfectly solved my doubt. 
Using localhost page generated by osm2po roteamente noticed that the link is made to link even disabling snapping. Logically thought to create more nodes in the network, but how can I do this without the topology?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the points, then it's as simple as

```
SELECT ST_DistanceSpheroid(pt1, pt2);
```

Or alternately

```
SELECT ST_Distance(pt1::geography, pt2::geography);
```

Comment: Paul, I think the question was about the distance using pgRouting ;-)